# merging 2 ResultSets with different fields

Tags: java, jdbc, merge, resultset

I have a question posted here:
[java nested while loop in result set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22239423/java-nested-while-loop-in-result-set/22240017?noredirect=1#comment33775160_22240017)

and the answer is correct, but unfortunately my sql server doesn't support insensitive, updatable ResultSets (the error says "`the cursor type/concurrency combination is not supported`")

What is the best way to merge results from 2 result sets to get the merged result shown below.

```
ResultSet set1: 
id | name
1  | A
2  | B
3  | C
...

ResultSet set2:
id | alias
1  | F
2  | G
2  | H
```

I want to print out:

```
Id: 1, Name: A, Alias: F
Id: 2, Name: B, Alias: G, H
```

FYI, the id is in ascending orders in both sets. Both ResultSets are results returned from sql queries
And I don't use UNION because the sql SELECT queries return different fields ('name' and 'alias')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could perform the following

```
Select s1.Id, s1.Name, s2.Alias
  from Set1 s1, Set2 s2
 where s1.Id= s2.Id
 order by s1.Id, s2.Alias
```

Or choose "Left Union" depending on whether you want to see the "C" row.
Now you will get:

```
 Id  Name  Alias
     1  A     F
     2  B     G
     2  B     H
```

I don't know of a way to get the multiple "Set2" rows into a single row